# Grails i18n validation error message with parent/child inheritence relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Lets say I have a **Person** class. Person has two children **Builder** and **Doctor**. 
The Person class comes with username attribute (as they often do). By inheritance of course the Builder and Doctor classes also have a username.

Now I want to beautify the i18n validation messages. I add the following thinking it will apply to all 3 of my classes

```
person.email.blank=Email is required
```

but it is not being used when validating objects of the child classes. If I add the following

```
doctor.email.blank=Email is required
builder.email.blank=Builder is required
```

I get the desired result, but it doesn't seem to be to be as DRY as it could be. 
Does anyone have any thoughts on this. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong!

Comment: If doctor and builder are inheriting properties of the person class, would you even need anything else besides the person.email.blank line?    Wouldn't person.email.blank be used?

Comment: @JohnMoses My experience has been that person.email.blank is not used by the subclasses, and instead the validation error defaults to the Grails default of something like "error with Class Person on field email"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using custom validator and a single message for all required message.

In the properties file:

```
default.isRequired= {3} is required
email=Email
otherProperty=Other property
```

in domain class:

```
email validator: {val, obj -> obj.isRequiredValidator(val, "email") }
email validator: {val, obj -> obj.isRequiredValidator(val, "otherProperty") }

private isRequiredValidator(val, key) {
  if (!val)
   return [default.isRequired, messageSource.getKey(key)]
}
```

Result after calling validate() will be "Email is required" and "Other property is required"

You can reuse the custom validator method by sharing it between domain classes.